# Android 5-10 / автозагрузка сервиса после презагрузки телефона

Tags: java, android, автозагрузка

Дoбрый день.
Надо чтобы после перезагрузки телефона сервис запускался по новой.

Знаю есть много похожих тем/гайдов, я перепробовал большинство, но они не работают (после перезагрузки доходит до onReceive, но сервис не стартует), в чем может быть проблема?

Мой код:

```
//MainActivity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

```
//Ресивер
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Log.e("AWM", "onReceive");
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }
}
```

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hidden"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Hidden">
        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".AutoStart"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запускайте сервис как Foreground

```
 startForegroundService()
```